# How to find Neural Network ZOOs?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, rnn

I have heard about the term Neural Network ZOOs, which are supposed to be repositories where there are a lot of pre-trained neural network models for many different applications, but I'm struggling to find them. Does anybody have some links for these kinds of repositories, especially for keras models?

Answer (score 0):

One "neural network zoo" is a collection of architecture visualizations from the [Asimov Institute](https://www.asimovinstitute.org/neural-network-zoo/).

Pre-trained Kera networks can be found in [Keras Applications](https://keras.io/api/applications/).